# What is the difference between "" and nothing

Tags: json

Hello I would like to know what is the difference between '' and nothing I mean for instance if I take this example :

```
"test":[""]
```

and

```
"test":[""]
```

Comment: you wrote both same

Answer (score 0):

Though you have given identical examples, I think you tried to provide these two:

```
"test":[""]
```

and this: `"test":[]`

For the first case, your test array length is 1. So, accessing `test[0]` will give you `""`
But for the second case, its length is 0. So no element in the later but for the first one you have `""`.
That's it.